# In MFC, how to add Buttons according to the user input

Tags: c++, mfc

What I want to achieve is that user can input a number in the Edit Control, and according to that number the exact same number of buttons will be created (in the same dialog would be the best).

How will I be able to achieve that?

Comment: By creating new `CButton` objects?

Comment: do you know how to create buttons without user input? Do you know how to react on user input?

Comment: a quick and dirty method would be to create buttons in the wizard but hide them, then when user enters value reveal the approp. number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically creating controls with MFC is a two-step process:

- Construct a C++ class instance that will represent the control by invoking the c'tor ([`CButton::CButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbutton-class#cbutton))
- Construct the actual control by calling [`CButton::Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbutton-class#create)

If you need to create `n` button controls, perform this sequence `n` times.

This solves the easy part. The more challenging issue is how to respond to button click messages. Since the [message map macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc) are strictly a static, compile-time way to wire up events with event handlers, they are difficult to use with dynamically created controls. If you can restrict your UI to a maximum number of button controls, you could wire up an event handler using [`ON_COMMAND_RANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc#on_command_range) or [`ON_CONTROL_RANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc#on_control_range) for the `BN_CLICKED` notification code.

All of that is non-trivial with several distinct solutions. You should probably ask a separate question in case you're interested in how to tackle that problem.

---

While that answers the question that was asked, a far easier solution would be to statically lay out the dialog with the maximum number of allowed buttons (e.g. in your .rc script), and dynamically change the *visibility* of controls in response to user input (see [`CWnd::ShowWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#showwindow)).

Doing that allows you to statically declare your message map entries. Since hidden windows (`SW_HIDE`) do not generate any input messages you don't have to do anything in addition to toggling visibility between `SW_HIDE` and `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE`.

Comment: You also have the option of disabling the buttons rather than hiding them.  That leads to a more consistent interface.

Comment: @mar That's another option as long as you remember to [never leave focus on a disabled control](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040804-00/?p=38243).

Comment: Very true, I've made that mistake before. The best solution is to create a function that disables a control and also handles associated focus fixup as needed.